# Error when compiling in AoT using an object with integers as key

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I have an enum file which contains all my route paths in an object like this:

```
export const mortgageFormEnum = {
 routes: {
    start: 0,
    whatsUp: 1,
    refinance: 17,
    newAddress: 19,
    deposit: 2,
    addBorrower: 3,
    primaryIncome: 4,
    secondaryIncome: 5,
    properties: {
      0: { url: '', name: 'Start' },
      1: { url: 'whats-up', name: 'Whats Up' },
      2: { url: 'deposit', name: 'Deposit' },
      3: { url: 'add-borrower', name: 'Add Borrower' },
      4: { url: 'primary-income', name: 'Primary Income' },
      5: { url: 'secondary-income', name: 'Secondary Income' }
    }
  }
}
```

When I compile using AoT, I get this error:

> Error during template compile of 'MortgageFormModule'   Name expected
>   in 'mortgageFormRoutes'
>       'mortgageFormRoutes' references 'mortgageFormEnum' at src\app\mortgage\mortgage-form.routes.ts(50,11)
>         'mortgageFormEnum' contains the error at src\app\mortgage\shared\mortgage-form.enums.ts(27,7).

Basically the error points to the properties object and complains that I am using an integer as the key instead of a name. 
Is this a bug? or how should I get around this? This enum file contains many other enums with the properties object (so I can map the values coming back from the server to its' title etc), while not applicable to my routes, is applicable to other objects so I can't delete it, in any case a javascript object can be defined using integers as keys so I have no idea why the compiler is complaining... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted this to the angular-cli team and it appears to be a bug.

FYI:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9890

Comment: The issue is in the Angular AOT compiler not the CLI. You will find that AOT implies that a number of JavaScript features are unsupported, and in some cases has a divergent implementation.